# Use VisualEditor.DynamicPickList with blank valule

Tags: lightning-aura-components, picklist, design-attributes

I have a component that uses VisualEditor.DynamicPickList to show active case types users can choose when configuring it on community layout.
Works like magic but now I want to reset one of the picklists and I'm not able to. Although the class returns blank value in VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows and I can choose it the change is never preserved.
How can I undo my selection and save a blank value?

Comment: Giving a blank value works fine, try giving a label to it (should not matter though)

Comment: Nope it's not I tried several times. I tried blank label and 'None' label with a null value. Neither can't be persisted. The builder says no changes have been maid and the page can't be published. When I click on the picklist again it shows as it the old value was still selected instead of the blank one.